# Can't add "markdown_to_html" filter to twig

Tags: php, twig, markdown

I want to use the `markdown_to_html` filter to render makrdown inside my template, so I tried following the [instructions](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html) in the docs but the filter is not added correctly. The error I get when rendering the template is *Message: Unknown "markdown_to_html" filter.*

Here's my code:

```
// Load twig and the markdown extension

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader("../templates");
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
  "cache" => "../cache/twig",
  "debug" => true,
  "autoescape" => false,
]);

use Twig\Extra\Markdown\DefaultMarkdown;
use Twig\Extra\Markdown\MarkdownRuntime;
use Twig\RuntimeLoader\RuntimeLoaderInterface;

$twig->addRuntimeLoader(new class implements RuntimeLoaderInterface {
  public function load($class) {
    if (MarkdownRuntime::class === $class) {
      return new MarkdownRuntime(new DefaultMarkdown());
    }
  }
});

// Read md file and render template

$markdown = file_get_contents("content/text.md");
try {
  echo $twig->render("template.phtml", ["text" => $markdown]);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The template:

```
  {% apply markdown_to_html %}
    {{ text }}
  {% endapply %}
```

I added `twig/twig` and `twig/markdown-extra`, both are version `3.0`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello. I think you miss to add the extension :
`$twig->addExtension(new MarkdownExtension());`

Comment: thx @GrenierJ that was it  — I misinterpreted that part of the instructions. Post as answer or I can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the extension with

```
$twig->addExtension(new MarkdownExtension());
```

Note how the docs say

> If you are not using Symfony, you must **also** register the extension runtime:

whily you did it **instead**